# How can I disable automatic epstopdf conversion of .eps figures?

Tags: texlive, epstopdf

As far as I understand my TexLive 2014 distribution performs automatic eps to pdf conversion for `\includegraphics` where it find only an .eps file. However I would like to disable this automatic conversion because it messes with my own Makefile and latexmk custom dependencies conversion scheme.

Is there a way to disable this automatic conversion in TexLive?

Comment: If there is only an eps and you disable the conversion the pdflatex run will give errors. Where is the point? How does your makefile handles this?

Comment: The makefile converts all off my figures (manly svg, some tiff, some eps) and I just would like to keep eveything in one place and avoid those ugly *-converted-to.pdf files mixed in. It's just a matter of taste,  everything would certainly work with the automatic conversion.

Comment: I do understand this. But if you convert your pictures *before* the pdflatex run, there should be no ugly *-converted-to-pdf-files.

Comment: For `filename.eps` use `\includegraphics{pdf_filename_you_expect_without_extension}`, not `\includegraphics{filename.eps}`. `pdflatex` will automatically use `pdf_filename_you_expect_without_extension.pdf` (assuming you do not have anything customized with `graphicx`'s `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\newcommand{\DoNotLoadEpstopdf}{}` before loading `graphicx`; the start of the file, before `\documentclass` is a good place.

From `pdftex.def`:

```
% In other words, by default .eps files will be automatically
% converted to .pdf files when outputting pdf.  This can be wrong!
% If the .pdf is the source, rather than the .eps, you should put
%  \newcommand{\DoNotLoadEpstopdf}{}
% before even the \documentclass line of your document.
```